# Create New Column That Takes Column Name Based on Value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with binary values that I want to summarize into one column. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame("User" = c("User A", "User B", "User C"), "quality 1" = c(0,0,1), "quality 2" = c(1,0,0), "quality 3" = c(0,1,0))
```

I'd like to run function that generates a dataframe like this:

```
summary <- data.frame("User" = c("User A", "User B", "User C"), "qualityNumber" = c("quality.2", "quality.3", "quality.1") )
```

For each row, the new variable ("qualityNumber") is assigned the column name from the original df that contains 1.

I have tried using dplyr and which(), but I can't figure it out.

My attempt:

```
summary = df %>%
mutate(
    qualityNumber= 
      colnames(df[which(2:4 == 1)])
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding to the same `df`:

```
df$qualityNumber <- apply(df[,-1],1,function(x) names(x)[which(x==1)])

    User quality.1 quality.2 quality.3 qualityNumber
1 User A         0         1         0     quality.2
2 User B         0         0         1     quality.3
3 User C         1         0         0     quality.1
```

Or selecting the columns after the task:

```
df[,c(1,5)]

    User qualityNumber
1 User A     quality.2
2 User B     quality.3
3 User C     quality.1
```

Comment: This is perfect; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
df$qualityNumber <- names(df)[max.col(df == 1, ties.method = "first")]
```

The result:

```
> df
    User quality.1 quality.2 quality.3 qualityNumber
1 User A         0         1         0     quality.2
2 User B         0         0         1     quality.3
3 User C         1         0         0     quality.1
```